# Does anybody here know about android multilevel listview app using data from MySQL?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, multi-level

I want to implement a multilevel listview app in android that populates data from a MySQL database. As it is, I have searched low and high through the Internet to find material to learn from, but to no avail. I am a tenderfoot in android programming; I would really appreciate it if anybody who has experience in doing a multilevel listview app using data from MySQL could share their knowledge with me. And if anybody could direct me to tutorials related to my problem, that is welcome too. Thanks.